# What are possible options to flatten an object due to weight and viscousity, or fake it :)

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, physics, fluid-simulation

I've modelled this kind of toothpaste piping. Trying out beziers etc.

Now I'd like to make it look as if the matter is being squished a bit, via gravity or some other technique.

[image]

The look I'm after is where two surfaces kind of melt together, or in this case where the bottom would sit

1. Flat on the ground surface
2. Bulge slightly outwards

[image]

This is not for animation. Just a still of modelling progress. I've been thinking I could use lattice, or bisect the bottom and re-create the surfaces.. or maybe go into sculpt mode and try something there. I feel that I do not want to model it by hand, simply because the vertices of the bezier mesh do not align, so much tweaking will be needed.

Perhaps I could have lofted shapes together instead. But toothpaste takes many forms, bezier mesh seems simple.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you're best bet would be to use sculpt mode. Another option could be to use physics, but I think that only works for animation.